# Capture Image using WP.1 store app

Tags: c#, camera, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an Windows Store App in WP8.1. I need to take photo through camera and save it and use it for showing but it throws exception everytime. My code is--

```
async private void capturePhoto_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

                StorageFile sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("My Picture", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
                ImageEncodingProperties img = new ImageEncodingProperties();
                await mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(img, sf);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

It throws an exception Object must be initailized and if I use InitalizeAsync it shows System.Exception and message is Text related to the Exception could not be found.If I use this code

```
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desired)
        {
            DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desired);

            if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
            else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera of type {0} doesn't exist.", desired));
        }

        async private void InitCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
            var captureManager = new MediaCapture();
            await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
            {
                StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
                PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.Photo,
                AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
                VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
            });
            StorageFile sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("My Picture", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            ImageEncodingProperties img = new ImageEncodingProperties();
            await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(img, sf);
        }
```

I found the error ------ The requested attribute was not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36E6)--
 Can anybody help?

[Link to my project named Camera](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2D07E008BB4FBF8C!117&authkey=!AEtf_qGHHEQlCiQ&ithint=file%2Crar)

Comment: Take a look [at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23606620/2681948) also ensure that you have declared the needed capabilities.

Comment: I tried this but I got an error --------------The text associated with this error code could not be found.--------which I described in my question

Comment: Where do you get this error? Also have you debugged your program?

Comment: I did it and error is on Initailize method and CapturePhotoToStorage method and I can not find the solution to it. I have updated my code with new error all I have tried.

Comment: Does `GetCameraID` return a valid camera device? Is it possible that you can share a sample?

Comment: GetCameraID returns a valid camera device and this is my actual code which i call on tap of textblock

Comment: Is it possible that you can share a sample with the problem?

Comment: I have added my code sample in my question at the bottom with both methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are couple of problems you are facing:

- you shouldn't declare *MediaCapture* in local scope
- you should [preview your photo before taking it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28301513/2681948)
- you should always *Dispose()* the *MediaCapture* - I think this may be the biggest problem, the first time you initialize it will work fine, but when you stop debugging you don't dispose the capture manager - in this case further initialization will fail unless you restart the phone. *MediaCapture* needs to be handeled carefully
- also watch out not to fire *Tapped* event multiple times

I've tried such code and works just fine:

```cs
private bool initialized = false;
private MediaCapture captureManager;
async private void capturePhoto_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (initialized) return;
    try
    {
        var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
        captureManager = new MediaCapture();
        await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
            PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
            AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
            VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
        });
        //      StorageFile sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("My Picture", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        //       ImageEncodingProperties img = new ImageEncodingProperties();
        //       img = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
        //        await captureManager.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(img, sf);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { (new MessageDialog("An error occured")).ShowAsync(); }
}

private void OffButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    captureManager.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I added this code but still I am not able to launch the camera. I am having trouble in even launching the camera

Comment: @Rohit Just adding the code above won't help you unless you check other things I've mentioned. Do a simple test: restart your phone, run above initialization and show preview of camera on the screen - can you see something, does it work?

Comment: I checked my code and it worked after I deleted the app and restarted it. Thanks for your help. Sometimes it throws error and needs to restart the phone

Comment: @Rohit It means that you hadn't freed the resources properly - what is the most important thing once dealing with *MediaCapture*. Keep that in mind - good luck.